# Get all keys of a JavaScript object whose value is true

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the object `pks` and would like to extract all keys where the value is `true`.

```
pks = {3: false, 7: true, 2: true}
```

Is there an underscore function that can return `[7, 2]`? I’ve tried `_.invert` but I lost one of the values in the process so I’m looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with builtin functions, no need for Underscore:

```
Object.keys(pks)
  .filter(function(k){return pks[k]})
  .map(Number)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
_.reduce(pks, function(memo, val, key){
  if (val) memo.push(key);
  return memo;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lodash:**

```
_.compact(_.map(pks, function(value, prop) {
  if(value) {
    return prop;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Object.entries(), filter() and map():

```js
const pks = {3: false, 7: true, 2: true};

const trueKeys = Object.entries(pks).filter(([_, v]) => v).map(([k, _]) => +k);

console.log(trueKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not an underscore function that does specifically this but there is a way you can do it yourself:

```
function getTrueKeys(obj) {
   var ret = [];
   for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === true) {
         ret.push(key);
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```